# python - tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
try:   
    from PIL import Image as Img
    import os
    import pytesseract as tss
except ImportError as error:
    raise Exception(str(e))

from passporteye import read_mrz
#So far you're using windows always do this; esp. if you've haven't add teseract.exe to PATH
#tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR'

def Get_mrz(image_file):
    print("This will take a while.")
    try:
        mrz=read_mrz(image_file,save_roi=True)
        print("Done")
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("THERE WAS AN EXCEPTION "+str(e))
    
    if mrz!=None:
        print(mrz)
    else:
        return "Cannot read text"
def Credits():
    print("This is work...")

#The test is below
Get_mrz("img/id_card2f.jpg")
Credits()
```

It keeps giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_stuff.py", line 28, in <module>
    Get_mrz("img/id_card2f.jpg")
  File "main_stuff.py", line 18, in Get_mrz
    raise Exception("THERE WAS AN EXCEPTION "+str(e))
Exception: THERE WAS AN EXCEPTION tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

but I dont know  why.Tesseract-ocr binary was succesfully installed and added to my PATH.
I know this because if I run `tesseract --version` in any directory  it gives

```
tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20200328
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.3 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.5
 Found libcurl/7.59.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2o (WinSSL) zlib/1.2.11 WinIDN libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.31.0
```

Comment: Did you install the PyPi package? https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Comment: Just checking but.. Is there any chance when you run tesseract --version you are already in this directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\  ?

Comment: @user3250052 no.I said 'any directory'

Comment: oh yeah. sorry. does it work if you pass the path explicitly like this tss.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'

Comment: @user3250052 Yes.I had gotten it 2 mins b4 u sent ur answer.Do u want to answer it so Ill upvote and accept ur answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the path explicitly like this

```
tss.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
```