# pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information

Tags: python, error-handling, python-tesseract

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('image1.jpg')

result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(result)
```

My question is may similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424318/python-tesseract-is-not-installed-or-its-not-in-your-path-see-readme-file-fo) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424318/python-tesseract-is-not-installed-or-its-not-in-your-path-see-readme-file-fo). But, there's no helpful answer for me...

Error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/istiak/PycharmProjects/image-to-text/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
> proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1823, in _execute_child
> raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/istiak/PycharmProjects/image-to-text/main.py", line 6, in 
> result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
> File "/home/istiak/PycharmProjects/image-to-text/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 409, in image_to_string
> return {
> File "/home/istiak/PycharmProjects/image-to-text/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 412, in 
> Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
> File "/home/istiak/PycharmProjects/image-to-text/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 287, in run_and_get_output
> run_tesseract(**kwargs)
> File "/home/istiak/PycharmProjects/image-to-text/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 259, in run_tesseract
> raise TesseractNotFoundError()
> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.

But, I have pytesseract right there..
[image]

[image]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300013/13146129) helpful for [him](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41035084/13146129). But, I am using Linux Fedora... Is there something just like this in Linux?

I tried to install `tesseract-ocr` [link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/tesseract+is+not+installed+or+it%27s+not+in+your+PATH.+See+README+file+for+more+information.)......

```
sudo snap install tesseract-ocr
sudo dnf install tesseract-ocr
```

Error : Unable to find a match: tesseract-ocr

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dnf install tesseract
```

If you are using Windows than you need to install [`Tesseract`](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rwW7OO6wGN8olJAyD6cQSYi4caSABoC_?usp=sharing) [@Bhargav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15358800/bhargav) gave that link. If you are using Ubuntu, Mint or something else..

You have to try

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

If you are using Arch than, visit the [link](https://snapcraft.io/install/tesseract/arch)